# WPF how do i get the selected treeviewitem on selecteditemchanged event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The sender of the event is the object inside the treeviewitem. However, it's not a dependencyobject so I don't think I can use ItemFromContainer to get the actual TreeViewItem. What should I do to get the actual treeviewitem that is selected?

i see that everyone is as confused by my question as I am by my problem.

according to the linked site, I can get my treeviewitem from the selecteditem property.  However, when I attempt to do this I get null because the sender is a SignalViewModel object instead of a TreeViewItem.

```
TreeViewItem treeViewItem = this.AvailableSignalsTreeView.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
```

this returns null for me but the debugger shows that the selected item is of type SignalViewModel.

All I'm trying to do is get multiselect capability for a treeview, which I was going to do using an example I saw that just toggles the treeviewitems.

```
 <TreeView
        Grid.Row="0"
        Background="Blue"
        Foreground="Orange"
        x:Name="AvailableSignalsTreeView"
        SelectedItemChanged="AvailableSignalsTreeView_SelectedItemChanged"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource available_signals_source}}"
        >

        <TreeView.CommandBindings>
          <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll"
                          Executed="AvailableSignalsTreeView_SelectAll"
                          CanExecute="AvailableSignalsTreeView_SelectAllCanExecute"/>
        </TreeView.CommandBindings>
        <TreeView.InputBindings>
          <KeyBinding
            Command="ApplicationCommands.SelectAll"
            Modifiers="Ctrl"
            Key="A"
            />
        </TreeView.InputBindings>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
          <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource ="{Binding Path = bits}" >
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Path = SignalName}" 
                />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock
                          Text="{Binding Path = BitNumber}" 
                          />
                      </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
          </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeView.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Add Bits to Signal" Click="AddBitToSignal" />
          </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.ContextMenu>
      </TreeView>
```

Comment: You want something like this : `var item = e.OriginalSource as TheItemYouExpect`.In TheItemYouExpect you can type `Image,Button`,whatever you expect the item to be.Hope i understand your question.

Comment: TreeView.SelectedItem? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditem.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Helper to search up the VisualTree
private static T FindAnchestor<T>(DependencyObject current)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
   do
   {
      if (current is T)
      {
         return (T)current;
      }
      current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
   }
   while (current != null);
   return null;
}

private void AvailableSignalsTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(
    object sender,
    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
{
    var treeViewItem = FindAnchestor<TreeViewItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
}
```

Comment: what order does templating take? 
I assumed the order was something like, create treeview, apply control template to treeview, create treeviewitems, apply control template for treeviewitems, then apply data templates to the stuff placed in the data templates.  Not sure why I didn't just search up the tree for it yesterday, but I guess i was confused and thought i needed to use getcontainerfromitem or something to get the treeviewitem.

Comment: actually I don't think that's going to work. e.OriginalSource doesn't contain the treeviewitem's content, rather it contains the treeview itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I was thinking of is this. Basically the selected item isn't a dependency object so I can't traverse the tree using them, and I have to instead get the container using the itemcontainer generator.

I thought I tried this yesterday, not sure why it wasn't working.

```
TreeViewItem tvi = tv.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(tv.SelectedItem) as TreeViewItem;
```